# Who to select as recipient in appreciation mails based upon situations

Tags: communication, manager

I am retiring from my managerial role and a new person is about to take my role., I remotely manage 35 member team over seas with a manager reporting to me.,
Anyway before leaving I want to appreciate A particular employee for his work who is in that 35 member Team.,

I have included my replacement manager and my reportee manager in the email ., is it necessary to cc the employee or its ok to appreciate just to managers and let them convey my Gratitude and appreciation

Answer (score 3):

Is it acceptable?  Sure.

Is it the right approach?  I'm hard-pressed to see why it would be.  If you want to express some appreciation to a particular employee, it would seem to be far more meaningful if that appreciation came directly from you rather than hoping that someone that is coming in to replace you (presumably knowing neither you nor this employee) expresses appreciation on your behalf.

Answer (score 2):

I can't think of any objection to you sending a note of appreciation to employee X with the note cc'ed to employee X's management. As long as everybody is in the loop, I think everything will be fine.

Regardless of which choice you make, the bottom line is that you everyone has to know how much you appreciate employee X's contribution. The one thing you shouldn't do is write just one person. If you send a message to just one person and that message ends up in that person's Spam box and that person doesn't check their Spam box, you are screwed because your message didn't get to anyone.